# stopping iphone screen from going to sleep/dimming even when the app isn't in the foreground

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

i am a completely new (and bewildered) ios developer here.

i would like to implement a feature in my app that stops the screen from turning off/ locking/ going to sleep automatically.

so far i have used UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true .

now this works when the app is open, in the foreground. but i would like idleTimerDisabled to be true even when the app is in the background.

i have thought about the app changing the autolock setting in the settings app for the user, although i'm not sure how to implement this.

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Apple does not give you control over the device's sleep behavior when your app is not currently in the foreground. You can learn more about the iOS app lifecycle and how background and foreground modes work here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle